# Java generics basics

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning programming in java using generic types and got a probably very basic question.

Where's the difference between the further two snippets?

1.)

```
public void build(House house) {
    // work only with house objects that extending House
}
```

2.)

```
public <T extends House> void build(T house) {
    // work only with house objects that extending House
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between these two methods with respect to what they can take in as parameters; however, in the latter example, one does have access to the specific type `T`.  Regardless, this example does not illustrate the power of generics.

As an example consider a `LinkedList` of `Node<T>` objects.  We can define a wrapper, `Node<T>`, which can hold an object of any type.  This is a very useful construct, as it allows us to write one piece of code that can be used for many different objects.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that inside the second function you have access to type type `T`, the type the caller used to access your method.

I can't think however of any way to use that type that would differ meaningfully from using `House` directly. It might make a difference with some other parameters or return types of the method.

Answer (score 0):

They are logically the same.

Although, on the second case the compiler can make some advanced verifications.

Let´s say there is are two subclasses of House called XHouse and YHouse.

We have the following source code:

```
XHouse house = build(yHouse)
```

This will fail if yHouse is an object of type YHouse and YHouse is not a subclass of XHouse.

Think of a generic as a sort of template. When you fill the generic argument, you sort of create a new method. In the example above, the **usage** of the generic method is virtually creating the following:

```
public XHouse void build(XHouse house) {
    // work only with XHouse objects that extending XHouse
}
```

Notice I even changed the comments.

Comment: Your example is good, but it requires that the return type is changed from void to T.

Comment: Yes, it does. But the author of the question amended that. The question needs editing. Which I just did.